slow wheel novement issue with nav2 and slam_toolbox in Gazebo
i'm currently working with nav2 and slam_toolbox in gazebo for autonomous driving. while the setup seems to be functioning correctly overall, i'm encountering an issue where the wheels are turning very slowly(gazebo runs at 30 fps so it is probably not a performance related problem), and i'm struggling to identify the root cause.
i suspect the gazebo diff_drive_controller might be the culprit, but despite adjusting inertia values, i haven't been able to resolve the issue. as someone new to ros2, i might be missing something obvious.
could someone experienced take a look at my repository here? any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
thank you!
